# using hudson and ant create datewise folder for each day where concern builds will be there

Tags: date, ant, hudson

Iam using hudson and ant, i want to create a build structure like according to the current date, date folder has to be created and whenever the scheduled build was done , the concern war has to be placed in that date folder, 
  so that it will be easy to pick up the war by the QA team, according to the date.

now I want to create a date folder according to the current date and to put the war in it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add to the Ant buildfile to do this?  If so, this might be a suitable starting point.  Use the Ant [`tstamp` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html) to generate the name for the directory for today's builds.  In the example here there is also a build timestamp generated, so that multiple builds per day can be kept.

```
<tstamp>
<format property="build.date" pattern="yyyyMMdd" />
<format property="build.time" pattern="HHmmss" />
</tstamp>

<property name="current.build.artifacts" value="${build.artifacts}/${build.date}" />
<mkdir dir="${build.artifacts}/${build.date}" />

<copy file="${build.war}" tofile="${current.build.artifacts}/${build.war}.${build.time}" />
```

You might also look at introducing a build number using the [`buildnumber` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html) or the `entry` feature of the [`propertyfile` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html).